# Firebase storage for dev and prod

Tags: android, firebase, build, production-environment, firebase-storage

How can I separate my firebase prod and dev storage with buildtypes or flavors in android ?

I already know how to separate the database but this doesn't apply to storage.
The problem is that the code to instantiate the storage doesn't rely on google-services.json but on a fixed url :
`FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://dev-app.appspot.com");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set in build.gradle (module level)

> ```
>  buildTypes {
>         debug {
>             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"gs://dev-app.appspot.com"'
>         }
>         release {
>             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"gs://prod-app.appspot.com"'
>         }
> ```

2. In your code use

   FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL);

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not the most robust way to separate your builds.  I have written a more comprehensive set of solutions in [this blog post on the Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).  Changing the default storage bucket is just like changing the default Database URL when dealing with google-services.json - you don't need to bake the constant value of the bucket URL into your code.

Comment: Hi Doug, sorry if I write after almost 2 year but reading your article I don't understand how to set a dev and prod storage inside my debug and release build types